# Implement stack with pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I try to implement a simple stack in c with pointers and struct but I think I have a problem with push or print. My program prints only the first Node.

If someone could help me to solve this

Here is my code

stack.h

```
/***********************************************************************
* stack.h
***********************************************************************/

#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef _STACK_H_
#define _STACK_H_

typedef struct Stack{
    int value;
    struct Stack* next;
}Stack;

Stack initStack();

bool push (Stack* s, int n);

int pop (Stack* s);

bool stackEmpty (Stack s);

void printStack (Stack s);

#endif
```

stack.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stack.h"

Stack initStack(){
    Stack s = {0, NULL};
    return s;
}

bool push (Stack* s, int n){
    if (stackEmpty(*s)){
        s->value = n;
        return true;
    }else{
        Stack stack = {n, s};
        s = &stack;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int pop (Stack* s){
    int value = s->value;
    s = s->next;
    return value;
}

bool stackEmpty (Stack s){
    if (s.value == 0 && s.next == NULL)
    return true;
return false;
}

void printStack (Stack s){
    Stack* b = &s;
    printf("Stack : \n");
    while(b != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", b->value);
        b = b->value;
    }
```

main

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    Stack stack1 = initStack();

    push(&stack1, 5);

    printStack(stack1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the address of a local variable here:

```
Stack stack = {n, s};
s = &stack;
```

You need to dynamically allocate it:

```
Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(*stack));
stack->value = n;
stack->next = s;
s = stack;
```

For consistency, I would recommend to take and return `Stack *` instead of `Stack`, and possibly rename `initStack` to `newStack`.

Comment: I'd use the `Stack*` as a convention in all the methods - i.e. Pass `Stack*` params not `Stack`. Consistency will avoid confusion!

Comment: @John3136 That's what I'm recommending in the last sentence in my answer (take and return being the most important part).

Comment: @JL2210 Thanks its works perfectly ! But I don't understand why I need to use param Stack** on push and i can't use Stack*, I tried also the second case and it didn't worked... I'm a bit confused about that

Comment: @Marc No, use `Stack *` for everything. For example, make `printStack` and `stackEmpty` take a `Stack *` and make `initStack` return a `Stack *`. Just make sure to dynamically allocate memory (with `malloc`) in `initStack`.